# How to handle dalvikvm VFY: unable to resolve virtual method on android?

Tags: android

I write some code like this:

```
String focusMode = camera.getParameters().getFocusMode();
```

but the getFocusMode() function was api level 5, my app's android:minSdkVersion="3" and android:targetSdkVersion="10"

so when I call this method on a android used api 3 or 4 will crash.

How can I handle the exception, I have tried try {} catch(Execption e) {}, but it can't catch. It also crash, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) method implemented from android docs is a good example how to implement functionality for different API levels. Basically you have to check for the method using reflection.